# Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call `myHolder.getAdapterPosition()` to look it up later

Tags: java, firebase

I have this error. All messages are deleted except the last or remaining message. I must take a step back in order for the message to be hidden. If I repeatedly click on Delete Message for the second time, the application stops.

```
private void deleteMessage(int position) {

        String myUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        String msgTimeStamp = chatList.get(position).getTimestamp();
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo(msgTimeStamp);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (ds.child("sender").getValue().equals(myUID)) {
                        ds.getRef().removeValue();

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Message deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "You cant delete only your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I tried to change this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder,  int i)
```

with this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, final  int i)
```